# Group elements in a List that share a common characteristic

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I  would like to order elements of a certain class by  a certain crtieria.

For example if I have this class :

```
public class Contact {

public string FirstName  { get; set; }
public string LastName{ get; set; }


}
```

and a list of this class :

```
        List<Contact> ContactList = new List<Contact>
        {

            new Contact{

             FirstName  = "John" ,
             LastName =  "Smith"
            }   ,


            new Contact{
             FirstName = "Andrew" , 
                LastName = "Wallace"

            }   ,
            new Contact{
             FirstName = "Andrew" , 
                LastName = "Smith"

            }   ,   new Contact{

             FirstName  = "John" ,
             LastName =  "Wallace"
            }   ,






        };
```

How can i Use Linq to order my `ContactList`  so that then it creates two lists one with Contacts whose firstname is John and the Other whose firstname is Andrew ?

This List is small but what if I have a huge list and i dont know what is inside the list and how can I order it with respect to the `FirstName`  characteristic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result =ContactList.GroupBy(c => c.FirstName)
            .Select(c => c.ToList())
            .ToList()
```

That will give you a `List<List<Contact>>` which contains two lists.First one  contains Johns and second one contains  Andrews.Here is the output:

[image]

Update:

According to your comment you can use a dictionary

```
var dict = ContactList.GroupBy(c => c.FirstName)
            .Select(c => c.ToList())
            .ToDictionary(x => x.First().FirstName, x => x);
```

After this you can get John's list with:

```
dict["John"]
```

Which give you a list that Contains all John's

Comment: so the var result will be a  list of list ?  List<List<ContactList>>  ?

Comment: @user2505650 yes.just use `ToList` after the Select.I updated my answer

Comment: Is it possible to change the name of the lists inside the "var" variable ?   For example if I would like to give to each of this list as a name the string of the FirstName ?

Comment: @user2505650 yes ofcourse :) key of the dictionary is string,you can replace it with any string.

Answer (score 0):

> This List is small but what if I have a huge list and i dont know what is inside the list and how can I order it with respect to the FirstName characteristic ?

For ordering it on the basis of first name, you can order your list with Linq like so.

```
var listOrderedByName = ContactList.OrderBy(cl => cl.FirstName);
```

and in this example you would end up with a single list where your contacts are ordered with all the Andrew contacts first and then all the John contacts after. This would work with a huge list as well.

> How can i Use Linq to order my ContactList so that then it creates two lists one with Contacts whose firstname is John and the Other whose firstname is Andrew ?

If you happen to know the specifics of your contact list and you just want one list with Johns and one list with Andrews you can do that with Linq like so.

```
var listWithJohnContactsOnly = ContactList.Where(cl => cl.FirstName == "John");
var listWithAndrewContactsOnly = ContactList.Where(cl => cl.FirstName == "Andrew");
```

This would give you two separate lists. One with just contacts with the first name "John" and the other with contacts with the first name "Andrew". If you were hoping to group them and end up with a list of lists (each list containing contacts with a particular first name) then you can use GroupBy like Selman22 suggested, and you wouldn't have to know about the specifics of the inside of your list.